# How to Bulk add/edit/delete entries in GAL global address list in the Exchange Online Programmatically

Tags: powershell, api, graph, office365, exchange-server

Powershell and Graph API.

How to Bulk add/edit/delete a few external entries in GAL global address list in the Exchange Online Programmatically on day to day basis.

Background: The source of entries exist in the third party system and need to update the GAL as data changes in the third party system. Updating the "default GAL" and not custom one so contacts are available to all users within the company.

Comment: `New-MailContact`, `Set-MailContact`, and `Remove-MailContact`?

Comment: @CrookedJ can you please post a sample for graph api ?